# Include Javascript in Webpack

Tags: webpack

```
<script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js"> </script>
<script src="/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"> </script>
<script src="/vendor/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/front.js"></script>
```

I purchased a template from the web, and I'd like to put the included JS via Webpack, but if I read correctly it isn't really possible? Of course most of those I should be able to get from npm, which should work, just a few others not...

Is there a way to include plain JS in Webpack afterall?

Answer (score 0):

Decided its smarter just to use it the way its expected. I used yarn add on as many as I can. Which was most.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4258 was also helpful